# Reduce CPU usage in Android

Tags: android, linux-kernel, cpu, processor

Need help in solving this mystery.

I have an android 4.4 quadcore device. Given quadcore, i assume that, the operations or load will be equally shared across all the cores when necessary.

Now i have started to check this "show cpu usage" in settings -> developer options -> show cpu usage.

I wondered looking at it which shows 12.0 / 11.7 / 8.0 . ( As per linux, this statistics is with respect to load which shows for 1 min / 5 mins / 15 mins )

Later i read this below link, whcih somewhat explains, what is this statistics about.

http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2009/07/31/understanding-load-averages

Mine being quadcore, i need to reduce this numbers below 2..

I have tried removing google apps which continously running over network etc. But still unable get it reduced below 8.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of `loadavg` is wrong here - it does not correspond to CPU utilization. It's common mistake as a lot of descriptions of `loadavg` mechanism are not perfectly right on what it calculates. If you look at the `proc(5)` man page, you can read:

```
The first three fields in this file are load average figures giving the
number of jobs in the run queue (state R) or waiting for disk I/O (state
D) averaged over 1, 5, and 15 minutes.
```

The most important thing here is the `"D"` (uninterruptible) state. The man page describes it as tasks waiting for I/O which is often interpreted as waiting for *disc* I/O which is not always the case. For various reasons, especially on embedded devices (like phones), device drivers often wait in uninterruptible state for various events which may fire very, very rarely.

On my totally idling Qualcomm SoC (4 core) based phone, I have 15 kernel threads in `"D"` state. All those threads are almost always sleeping but they do count to active task making my `loadavg` always higher than 15.

### Conclusion

`loadavg` is not a metric you should look for. Take a look at CPU utilization (like the output of `top` command) if you want to see how much CPU is actually used.

Comment: Very convincing.. Do you think android should have renamed "show cpu usage" as "show cpu load" ?

Comment: @SanjayHerle: It's just a name and it's for developers so they probably don't care. They show you 3 numbers so if you know what they mean, you know it's `loadavg`. Also, this setting will show you little more than just `loadavg`, there are some graphic bars showing real CPU usage, etc. As always - to get conclusion from any debugging information, you really have to understand what it actually shows so the name isn't really that important.